# Why can't the scanner input numbers again when try catch and while collocation

Tags: java

```
    int a = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    

    do {
        try {
            System.out.println("try to get a num");
            a = sc.nextInt();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("dont type Decimal point");
            
            
        }
    } while (a == 0);

    System.out.println(a);
```

oh I guess its a very simple question...

when I type `2.5` to `a`,

I hope it will let me enter `a=sc.nextInt()` again,

But it did not operate,

It will repeat "don't type Decimal point" in the end,

I just want to make a function that allows the user to check and re-enter when the input number is not an integer

Thank you for your guidance

Have a nice and happy day

Comment: Problem: `nextInt()` is not consuming the input in case of it not containing a valid `int`. So it is still there when the loop is repeated. Prove: add `System.out.println(sc.nextLine());` as last statement inside the `catch` block to show what would be read next (kind of solves the problem since it is consuming {reading} the input line)

Comment: (in other words, since `2.5` is not being read, `nextInt` will try to read it again and again (looping))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can check if the `Scanner object` has an `int` available in its input as the next token.*

`hasNextInt()` is a scanner function which does just that. Here is the method description:

> `public boolean hasNextInt()`

> *Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int
> value in the default radix using the nextInt() method. **The scanner does not advance
> past any input.***

Here is the code to do this:

```
int a = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
do
{
    System.out.print ("Enter an integer: ");

    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) a = scanner.nextInt();
    else
    {
        //Print the error message stating the expected input and input found
        System.out.println ("Invalid input.");
        System.out.println ("Expected input: integer");
        System.out.println ("Found: " + scanner.next());
        System.out.println ();
    }
} while (a == 0);

System.out.println(a);
```

*In the solution above we have **prevented any exception from happening** using `hasNextInt()` and discarded all the wrong inputs in the `else` part using `next()` method.*

*The code you provided can also be updated to work in a similar manner*. However, *instead of preventing the exception, we will wait for it to happen and then handle the wrong input in the `catch` block.*

Here is your updated code:

```
do
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Try to get a num");
        a = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       //Print the error message stating the expected input and input found
       System.out.println ("Invalid input.");
       System.out.println ("Expected input: integer");
       System.out.println ("Found: " + scanner.next());
       System.out.println ();
       a = 0;
    }
} while (a == 0);
```

I hope I have helped you. *Do comment if you face any problems with this solution.*

Comment: note1: first solution will just ignore any wrong input, no error message to user -  this can be desired, *or not*... sure better that a never ending loop [ : - ) Note 2: I would also add the wrong input in the error message (second code) - easier for user to understand, developer to *debug*

Comment: (for note 1: it is easy to add error message to `else` in case of invalid input)

Comment: @user15244370 Thank you for the feedback. I have updated both my codes to display error message along with the expected input and  input received.